# Social Media Profile Gem for Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, social-networking

I am trying to find a gem that will allow me to add social media(Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, and Google+) to client profiles of my app.
Like this images: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgPPz.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55BtG.jpg). How can i do? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you asking about social medial login?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify your App with facebook, twitter etc. by getting an API from their site. You can find more details on facebook.com developers etc. 
https://developers.facebook.com/
Than you can ask for the information of the user and store them into you database.